# how to get item value from ListView setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

Listview setOnItemClickListener in getItemAtPosition give item position not give value. wheb click on Listview item then give Error : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String. I will try to after .toString it's give integer value. so, How to get Item value Listview item.

Code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
     val query : String = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
     searchView?.setQuery(query,true)
}
```

Create Custom ListView Using BaseAdapter.

SearchAdapter.kt

```
class SearchAdapter(val searchList : ArrayList<Search>, val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return searchList.size
        }
    
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return position
        }
    
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    
            val convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.textview_list,parent,false)
            val image = convertView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewHistory)
            val textView = convertView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_list_view)
            val imageClear = convertView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewClear)
            val search = searchList.get(position)
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24)
            textView.text = search.search
    
            return convertView
        }
    }
```

Comment: How the `Search` looks like?

Comment: try this code. `val query = searchList.get(position)`

Answer (score 0):

in SearchAdapter :

```
 override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
      return searchList.get(position)
 }
```

in setOnItemClickListener :

```
 val search = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as Search
 val query = search.query
```